# Swift - delete Notification with dynamic identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an input for the user to set up a notification. It works fine and it's being triggered on the input date, but since the user is able to delete a specific notification from a table view, I need to add a function that removes a notification with a specific identifier.

My approach was to set up a dynamic identifier which changes with every input. It kind of works, but it mixes up the notification which is to delete - I reckon that's because after every added notification, the array is being sorted. Can anyone figure out a way for this to work or is there a better approach?

**My approach:**

```
func setAlert() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = notifTitle.text!
        content.body = notifDescribtion.text!
        content.badge = 1

        let date = datePicker.date

        let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: String(notStructArray.count), content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            notStructArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)

            defaults.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(notStructArray), forKey: "notStructArray")
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [String(indexPath.item)])

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out a way to solve this. I solely added and `id` to the struct. With every added notification this `id` is increasing by one. The notifications identifier is this `id` and when a notification is selected to be deleted, the `id` is being fetched and the notification removed.

```
func createStructArray() {
        notId += 1
        defaults.set(notId, forKey: "notId")
        let notificationData: not = not(title: notifTitle.text!, desc: notifDescribtion.text!, date: datePicker.date, type: notificationType, id: notId)
        notStructArray.append(notificationData)
        notStructArray.sort(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    }

func setAlert() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = notifTitle.text!
        content.body = notifDescribtion.text!
        content.badge = 1

        let date = datePicker.date

        let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: String(notId), content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            let array = notStructArray[indexPath.item]
            let id = array.id
            notStructArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)

            defaults.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(notStructArray), forKey: "notStructArray")

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [String(id)])

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```